# Materialize radio button doesn't work

Tags: css, materialize

I tried to make a tab with radio buttons inside the indices using materialize framework, but they don't load in page:

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab ">
    <a href="#requerimentos">
      <p>
        <label for="green">GREEN</label>
        <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="green" />
      </p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab ">
    <a class="active" href="#indicacoes">
      <p>
        <label for="red">RED</label>
        <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="red" />
      </p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab ">
    <a href="#leis">
      <p>
        <label for="black">BLACK</label>

        <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="black" />
      </p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="requerimentos" class="col s12">
  <p>Tab 1</p>
</div>
<div id="indicacoes" class="col s12">
  Tab 2
</div>
<div id="leis" class="col s12">
  Tab 3
</div>
```

Why the radio buttons do not appear inside the tab? tks

Comment: you should not insert an input inside an a tag ... both of them are clickable ... so wich is supose to receive the click event ? Beside a is inline, you should reset its display to anything but inline ;) .. if you did not. We have none of your css here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry i didn t understand what you asked. You want the radio button inside a tab? or you want the radio button as a tab title?

if you want radio button inside a tab, this is working :

```
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab ">
        <a href="#requerimentos">Green</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab ">
        <a class="active" href="#indicacoes">red</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab ">
        <a href="#leis">black</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="requerimentos" class="col s12">
    <p>Tab 1</p>
    <form action="#">
    <p>
      <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" />
      <label for="test1">Red</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" />
      <label for="test2">Yellow</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="test3"  />
      <label for="test3">Green</label>
    </p>
      <p>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test4" disabled="disabled" />
        <label for="test4">Brown</label>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="indicacoes" class="col s12">
    Tab 2
</div>
<div id="leis" class="col s12">
    Tab 3
</div>
```

Comment: this should be a comment ;)

Comment: oops sorry i m new. :( it seems that i need 50 reputation to give a comment :(

Comment: Its allright, just be patient, after a few good answers you'll be able to comment for ever . But now,  some would downvote your "short comment answer",

Comment: i edited it ^^ with a possible answer, but thank you for your explanation

Comment: Tks for aswer @raoon, each tab needs a radio button, activating the tab after selecting the radio.

Comment: I don t think it s possible to do this. radio button (input) was done to be embed into a form in order to send it on submit. If you want to use something who looks like radiobuttons into your <a></a>. You will have to use some css animation + some js to fake a radiobutton on your tabs titles

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="#">
    <p>
      <label>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" checked />
        <span>Red</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" />
        <span>Yellow</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio"  />
        <span>Green</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" disabled="disabled" />
        <span>Brown</span>
      </label>
    </p>
  </form>
```